# Would like to understand the following conditional probability.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I want to understand the following conditional probability and finally how to compute them.

$T$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$. For any $s > 0$, compute,
$$P(T > t + s | T > s)$$

The density function, $f(x) = e^{-\lambda x}$, is defined where $x>0$ or $0$ otherwise.

Now my intuition,
$$P(T > t + s | T > s) = \frac{P(T > t+s \;\cap\; T>s)}{P(T>s)}$$
$$= \frac{1 - P(s \le T \le t+s)}{1-P(T \le s)}\;\;\; (1)$$

I transformed $P(T>t+s\;\cap\;T>s)$ into $1 - P(s \lt T \le t+s)$. Is this correct ? Now in eqaution-$(1)$ I can replace them by the cumulative distribution formula. I need help whether my understanding is correct or not. Moreover should I also consider some bounds on $t$, because the problem does not mention any bounds on it.

Comment: Note that $\{T>t+s\}\cap\{T>s\}=\{T>t+s\}$. I would use this fact instead of transforming $P[T>\cdot]$ into $1-P[T\leq \cdot]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that $P(T>t+s, T>s)=1-P(s<T \le t+s)$ because the complementar of $(T>t+s) \cap (T>s)$ is $(T \le t+s) \cup (T \le s)$.

As @fKonrad says in the comments, use the fact that $(T>t+s) \subseteq (T>t)$.

Comment: The complement of $\{T>t+s\}\cap\{T>s\}$ is $\{T\leq t+s\}$, not  $\{T\geq t+s\}\cup \{T\leq s\}$

Comment: Thanks, @fKonrad, I fixed the typo.

Comment: Thanks @CélioAugusto and fKonrad for the help. I understood where I was missing.